# Find a model that makes this true $\forall x \forall y(Fx \Rightarrow Rxy)$

Tags: logic, symbolic-computation

Symbolic logic help. Find a model that makes this true

$\forall x \forall y(Fx \Rightarrow Rxy)\Rightarrow \forall x \forall y(Fx \Rightarrow Ry)$

### My attempt

$v(\forall x Fx)$= true iff for all $d$ in the domain $v(Fd)=t$ and $f$ otherwise.

My example:

Domain: $\{\text{Brazil, USA, Germany} \}$

(Interpretation) $I(F)=Brazil$

$I(R)=Brazil$

To be honest, I don't quite understand...

After edits

Attempt 2:

Domain: $\{\text{Brazil, USA, Germany, Argentina} \}$

$I(F):$ Country in South America

$I(x)$ Brazil

$I(y)$:Argentina

$I(R)$: Countries that speak a Latin language

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Instead of interpreting the predicates as sets, I would recommend coming up with an informal interpretation of $F$ and $R$ as a concept. For example, you could say $F(x)$: $x$ is a country in South America, and $R(x,y)$: $x$ plays soccer better than $y$. ... except this one doesn't work, since that would mean that any country in South America plays soccer better than any country ... including itself!  So, try to come up with something that does work.

Comment: I made edits with a second attempt but I am still not sure if i am getting this right. In class, we learned to do this with interpretations

Comment: @combostudent  Note that $R$ takes *two* arguments .. so $R$ needs to be a 2-place relation. So something like 'is smaller than' or 'has the same size as'.

Comment: @combostudent Also, variables don't get interpreted!  So, there is no auch thing as $I(x)$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the formula: $R$ has two arguments on the left and one on the right.

Comment: @Larry Huh! I had not noticed that before ... Maybe the OP chaged the post or maybe I was just looking at the title. And I think a real posibility is that the OP didn't copy down the formula corectly, since while it is of course perfectly ok to have a 1-place R as well as a 2-place R, it is typically avoided to avoid confusion. Anyway, good eyes, thanks!